# Tox multiple install_command

Tags: python, tox

How can I pass several commands to tox?

This is my try:

```
[tox]
install_command =
    python -m pip install --no-deps --install-option='--parallel 8' .
    python -m pip install {opts} {packages}
```

The previous configuration produce this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/tox", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('tox==3.14.5', 'console_scripts', 'tox')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tox/session/__init__.py", line 44, in cmdline
    main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tox/session/__init__.py", line 64, in main
    config = load_config(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tox/session/__init__.py", line 80, in load_config
    config = parseconfig(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tox/config/__init__.py", line 269, in parseconfig
    ParseIni(config, config_file, content)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tox/config/__init__.py", line 1149, in __init__
    raise tox.exception.ConfigError(
tox.exception.ConfigError: ConfigError: py27 failed with ConfigError: 'install_command' must contain '{packages}' substitution at Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tox/config/__init__.py", line 1125, in run
    results[name] = cur_self.make_envconfig(name, section, subs, config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tox/config/__init__.py", line 1289, in make_envconfig
    res = env_attr.postprocess(testenv_config=tc, value=res)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tox/config/__init__.py", line 241, in postprocess
```

Comment: FYI, there is a tracking issue at https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/715 for introducing `install_commands`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`install_command`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command):

> Determines **the command** used for installing packages into the virtual environment

(emphasize mine — *phd*)

I.e. `install_command` must be a single command, not a list. If you need to run several commands create a shell script and use it as the `install_command`.